# Is there a way to pass context to bind in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm inside a javascript object (vr roxx :) ), but every time I do an event bind with jQuery I have to include the main object instance's context through the data parameter in order to work with it. Isn't there an easy/neat way to do this in jQuery?

```
var oink = 
{
    pig: null,

    options:    
    {
        showPigMom: 0
    },

    init: function(pigObj)
    {

        //Show the pigmom
        $(this.doc).bind('keyup click', {o: this}, function(e)
        {
            var o = e.data.o;
            if (o.options.showpath)
                o.doWhatever();
        });

    ...
```

Comment: ...and in this object he had a pig: o, e.data.o....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use the [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function

```
init: function(pigObj)
{
    //Show the pigmom
    $(this.doc).bind('keyup click', $.proxy(function(e) {
        if (this.options.showpath)
            this.doWhatever();
        $(e.currentTarget).text(); // use this to access the clicked element
    }, this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this.doc).bind('keyup click', function() {
        if (self.options.showpath) self.doWhatever();
    });
}
```

Comment: $.proxy() or _.bind() should be preferred over the old school with explicit context variables

Comment: `proxy` looks cleaner, but what's wrong with the old school, @mPrinC?

Answer (score 2):

```
init: function() {
    $(this.doc).bind('keyup click', function() {
       if (this.options.showpath) this.doWhatever();
       $(e.currentTarget).text(); // use this to access the clicked element
    }.bind(this))
}
```